# Append field to a list

Tags: python

how can i extract just the value?

I have this code :

```
data = []
with open('city.txt') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        data.append(row[3])
```

That appends to the list the following (list is massive):

[....... " 'id': 'AX~only~Mariehamn'", " 'id': 'AX~only~Saltvik'", " 'id': 'AX~only~Sund'"]

How can i just append to the list the value of key 'id' ?

i just want to append this to the list: `AX~only~Saltvik`, and so on ?

city.txt is file containing the following(90k line file) :

```
{'name': 'Herat', 'displayName': 'Herat', 'meta': {'type': 'CITY'}, 'id': 'AF~HER~Herat', 'countryId': 'AF', 'countryName': 'AF', 'regionId': 'AF~HER', 'regionName': 'HER', 'latitude': 34.3482, 'longitude': 62.1997, 'links': {'self': {'path': '/api/netim/v1/cities/AF~HER~Herat'}}}
{'name': 'Kabul', 'displayName': 'Kabul', 'meta': {'type': 'CITY'}, 'id': 'AF~KAB~Kabul', 'countryId': 'AF', 'countryName': 'AF', 'regionId': 'AF~KAB', 'regionName': 'KAB', 'latitude': 34.5167, 'longitude': 69.1833, 'links': {'self': {'path': '/api/netim/v1/cities/AF~KAB~Kabul'}}}

so on ....
```

when i print(row) in the for loop statement i get the following(this is just las line of the output):

```
["{'name': 'Advancetown'", " 'displayName': 'Advancetown'", " 'meta': {'type': 'CITY'}", " 'id': 'AU~QLD~Advancetown'", " 'countryId': 'AU'", " 'countryName': 'AU'", " 'regionId': 'AU~QLD'", " 'regionName': 'QLD'^C: 152.7713", " 'links': {'self': {'path': '/api/netim/v1/cities/AU~QLD~Basin%20Pocket'}}}"]
```

Comment: Could you print the value of just one `row`?

Comment: Have you tried accessing the field like ``row[3]['id']``

Comment: please publish an example of `city.txt`

Comment: i have updated the content.

Comment: Can you post the structure of city.txt. A string including the id and value is being appended, so it would be easiler if we can see the txt file structure. Otherwise, i'll need a split and trim/replace/substring, but that might not be needed at all if we can see what the city.txt file contains.

Comment: @PETERSTACEY i hvae updateded the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is assuming that your output is exact, and that each value appended to your list is along the lines of a string, `" 'id': 'AX~only~Mariehamn'"`.

This means that in the base CSV file, the id and value are stored together as a string. You can get the second value through various string functions.

```
for row in readCSV:
    data.append(row[3].split(": ")[1].strip("'"))
```

The above code splits the string into a list with two parts, one before the colon and one afterwards: `[" 'id'", "'AX~only~Mariehamn'"`. Then, it takes the second value and strips the 's, resulting in a clean string.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `row[3]` is a string representing a key, value pair.
I would split it further and select only the value portion:

```py
data = []
with open('city.txt') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        data.append(row[3].split(':')[1][2:-1]
```

`[2:-1]` is to remove the `'` and a space.

Comment: I guess the format is not consistent then. Try @Leonis Supremem's answer.